# Where should loop be used to generate dummy data for SwiftUI preview?

Tags: swift, swiftui

`preview` is a static function and it makes using instance variable inside it impossible.

One way is to create data manually like the code below, it works but it does not scalable if say 1000 rows are needed.

```
static var data = [
    Item(id: UUID())
]
```

The question is, where is a good place to generate dummy data in a `for` loop? In this case how to generate a list of items for preview purposes?

```
struct MyListView: View {
    let items: [Item]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in
            item.id
        }
    }
}

struct MyListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    // Works but not every elegant :(
    static var dummyItems = [
        Item(id: UUID())
    ]

    static var previews: some View {
        MyListView(items: dummyItems)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the items for the preview with a closure that is called immediately to initialize the static var:

```
struct MyListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var items: [Item] = {
        var items = [Item]()
        for _ in 1...5 {
            items.append(Item(id: UUID()))
        }
        return items
    }()
    
    static var previews: some View {
        MyListView(items: items)
    }
}
```